# "Cannot cast" Subclass to Superclass

Tags: java, android, inheritance, casting

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {...}

ListFragment listFragment = new MyListFragment();
ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) new MyListFragment();
```

Both lines don't compile with "Cannot cast from MyListFragment to ListFragment".

Comment: It is not the *same* ListFragment type then or the MyListFragment is not the one posted. The "upcast" is not needed.

Comment: What? It's non-generic.

Comment: Perhaps it's from a different *import*?

Comment: What is from a different import? ListFragment is the only imported class.

Comment: Imported from the *same* package?

Comment: @Kurian u may have two classes of the same name in different package inside ur project. So due to that. user is saying that if i am not wrong.

Comment: No, ListFragment is a framework class any MyListFragment is in my own package. What does that matter; I didn't face this kind of problem in .NET.

Comment: Oh I see what happened. Eclipse auto imported the same class from a totally different package instead of the one I am using EVERYWHERE ELSE!

Comment: @Kurian yep... that happens sometime. Good catch.

Comment: Eclipse's algorithm for suggesting fixes for missing imports takes no account of what you are using in other classes in your codebase.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really just a careless mistake.  (Sorry ... but this Q&A is unlikely to help future visitors.)

Comment: Actually I disagree Stephen. Future visitors with the wrong import causing a cast to fail could well be helped.

Comment: It auto-imported the package as I typed. If I had to click "Fix" I would have spotted it instantly.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is definitely valid, so there must be something outside the code you describe which is causing the problem. The following code compiles.

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

private void test() {
    B b = new B();
    A a = b;
    A a2 = (A)b;
    A a3 = new B();
    A a4 = (A)new B();
}
```

Most likely you have a bad import, two classes with the same name and you have imported one from the wrong package.

Comment: Surely Tim B is correct , what you are trying to do is completely acceding with oops laws.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid

```
ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) new MyListFragment();


ListFragment listFragment =new MyListFragment();
```

As far as OOPS is concerned check this example.

```
  class SuperClass {}  
  class SubClass extends SuperClass {  
    public static void main(String[] x) {  
      SubClass sub = (SubClass) new SuperClass();      //1. ClassCastException   

       SuperClass sup = (SuperClass) new SubClass();    
       SubClass sub1 = (SubClass) sup;                //2. ok, why?  
   }  
 }
```

Because Compiler checks for only type and JVM checks for value.

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me :s

Comment: Please you proper OO terminology in your answers.  If you don't know the terminology, please learn it ... before you answer any more questions like this.

Comment: Confusing and not understandable

Comment: I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: No compilation error in my IDE.Both are valid problem may be different.